# Objective Sharpie Material Components

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, material-design, objective-sharpie, xamarin-binding

I am attempting to create Xamarin bindings for Google's [Material Components for iOS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/)
but receive errors regarding missing headers when using Objective Sharpie.

First Step:

```
sharpie pod init ios MaterialComponents
```

Result:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing MDFInternationalization (1.0.4)
Installing MDFTextAccessibility (1.2.0)
Installing MaterialComponents (48.0.0)
Installing MotionAnimator (2.8.1)
Installing MotionInterchange (1.6.0)
Installing MotionTransitioning (5.0.0)
```

Second Step:

```
sharpie pod bind
```

Result:

```
build/Release-iphoneos/MaterialComponents/MaterialComponents.framework/Headers/MDCFeatureHighlightAccessibilityMutator.h:19:9: fatal error:
  'MDFTextAccessibility/MDFTextAccessibility.h' file not found
#import <MDFTextAccessibility/MDFTextAccessibility.h>
```

I've attempted to copy the missing headers from the other dependent libraries into the MaterialComponents.framework/Headers folder but it still results with this final failure.

```
/private/var/folders/jb/wcx6dzt15jl5n909kqg52hj00000gn /T/com.xamarin.ObjectiveSharpie/d70c609622ae4bb0b3ceaccfd8613bae.h:1:9: fatal  error:
  could not build module 'MaterialComponents'
  @import MaterialComponents;
```

How can I get Objective Sharpie to create the bindings when the MaterialComponents piece has references to other libraries?

Comment: You can try to use [MaterialComponentsXamarin](https://github.com/ilap/MaterialComponentsXamarin) directly.

Comment: The current version for material components for iOS is 48, I am trying to update ilap’s repo from version 39.

Comment: Hi Jamie, let me know if you're successful in doing this. I'm facing the same issue. If you want to get in touch to work this out together, my email is [my-username at gmail]. ilap's repo (together with his other repo with utility shell scripts) contains what I believe is sufficient information to update it, but I think it will require some serious focus. Did you try contacting him?

Comment: I contacted him just to confirm that he used sharpie. I’ll take a look at the scripts again.